# how to change background color of multiple td elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm unable to change the background color of multiple td elements in a table using jquery.

HTML code :

```
<td id="trueValue">/com/website/seo/</td>

<td id="trueValue">/com/website/seo/</td>

<td id="falseValue">/com/website/seo/</td>

<td id="falseValue">/com/website/seo/</td>
```

Jquery code :

```
 $("td").each(function() {
 var i = $(this).attr("id");
 if (i == "trueValue") {
    $(i).css("background-color", "green");
    }
 });
```

The above jquery is doing nothing. Can someone correct my code please?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using same ids multiple times? Its wrong...

Comment: Thanks for this. Rory or Usman, is there a way I can correct my HTML? I'm sorry, I'm new to web development. So, please suggest me how I can proceed. Thanks

Comment: @harshavmb I added an answer for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`. Your HTML in this example would be invalid. If you want to group elements, use classes. Then you can just select the elements by class and apply the styling to them, like this:

```js
$('.truevalue').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="truevalue">/com/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="truevalue">/com/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="falsevalue">/com/website/seo/</td>
    <td class="falsevalue">/com/website/seo/</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have same `id` multiple times in a single web page. If it is very necessary you can use html5 [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute.

```js
$("td[data-id='trueValue']").addClass("highlight");
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-id="trueValue">/com/website/seo/</td>

      <td data-id="trueValue">/com/website/seo/</td>

      <td data-id="falseValue">/com/website/seo/</td>

      <td data-id="falseValue">/com/website/seo/</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Table to create table rows and its descriptions.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="falseValue"> XYZ </td>
    <td id="trueValue"> ABC </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("td").each(function() {
  var i = $(this).attr("id");
  if (i === 'trueValue') {
    $(this).css({
      'backgroundColor': 'green',
      'color': 'white'
    });
  }

});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rittamdebnath/p3fe1hv5/